# How can I extract the location of the Stateflow blocks in a given Simulink model?

Tags: simulink, stateflow

I have a Simulink model and I would like to extract the location of the Stateflow blocks it contains. I am looking for a command inspired by [this command that gives the total number of blocks](http://blogs.mathworks.com/simulink/2009/08/11/how-many-blocks-are-in-that-model/). How could I do this or where can I find more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find all Stateflow blocks:

```
Stateflow_blocks = find_system('your simulink model','MaskType','Stateflow')
```

Afterwards, get the positions:

```
for block = Stateflow_blocks
  get_param(block,'Position')
end
```

Comment: The first statement already gives me the path of the respective Stateflow blocks. What is the purpose of the second command (for loop) exactly?

Comment: I have assumed that you wanted physical location of the blocks on the screen :-)